# Mediator pattern implementation for game messaging

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mediator

I am building out a MUD game engine and want my objects to communicate with each other. There is a wide range of message types that will be sent around, all of which implement IMessage.

I adopted the Mediator pattern to facilitate passing the messages around to objects that have subscribed for publications. Is the pattern being used properly here?

#### INotificationCenter and implementation

The interface represents what objects will interact with when they want to subscribe to publications for a specific `IMessage` type. The ChatCenter is implemented as a singleton and will ultimately end up with the `Dictionary` being changed to a `ConcurrentDictionary` for thread-safety.

```
public interface INotificationCenter
{
    ISubscriptionHandler Subscribe<T>() where T : class, IMessage;

    void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage;
}

/// <summary>
/// The mediator for all messaging
/// </summary>
public class ChatCenter : INotificationCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of subscribed listeners
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<Type, List<ISubscriptionHandler>> listeners =
        new Dictionary<Type, List<ISubscriptionHandler>>();

    private static ChatCenter _centerSingleton = new ChatCenter();

    private ChatCenter()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribe publications for the message type specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISubscriptionHandler Subscribe<T>() where T : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(T);

        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            listeners.Add(messageType, new List<ISubscriptionHandler>());
        }

        // TODO: Move instancing of the handler in to a factory that does a lookup on <T> and returns the right handler.
        var handler = new ChatMessageHandler();
        listeners[messageType].Add(handler);

        return handler;
    }

    public static ChatCenter CurrentCenter
    {
        get
        {
            return _centerSingleton;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the specified message to all subscribers
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var handler in listeners[typeof(T)])
        {
            message.Dispatch(handler);
        }
    }

    internal void Unsubscribe<T>(ISubscriptionHandler handler) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        listeners.Remove(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

#### ISubscriptionHandler and implementation.

The subscription handlers are what are used to define what happens when a publish happens. At the moment, they just provide predicates and an Action to invoke. A non-generic type is used so that my `ChatCenter` does not have to be generic. There are different types of chat messages that can be used.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a contract to Types wanting to subscribe to published messages 
/// with conditions and a callback.
/// </summary>
public interface ISubscriptionHandler
{
    ISubscriptionHandler If(Func<IMessage, bool> condition);

    ISubscriptionHandler Dispatch(Action<IMessage> message);

    void Unsubscribe();
}    

/// <summary>
/// Processes a subscription message.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessageType">The type of the message type.</typeparam>
public interface ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessageType> : ISubscriptionHandler
{
    void ProcessMessage(TMessageType message);
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles chat message subscriptions
/// </summary>
public class ChatMessageHandler : ISubscriptionProcessor<ChatMessage>
{
    private List<Action<IMessage>> callbacks = new List<Action<IMessage>>();

    private List<Func<IMessage, bool>> conditions = new List<Func<IMessage, bool>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a callback for when a chat message is published by the MessageCenter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISubscriptionHandler Dispatch(Action<IMessage> message)
    {
        this.callbacks.Add(message);
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides conditional values that will be evaluated upon a publish from the MessageCenter.
    /// If any of the results return false, the callbacks will not be dispatched.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISubscriptionHandler If(Func<IMessage, bool> condition)
    {
        this.conditions.Add(condition);
        return this;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this.callbacks.Clear();
        this.conditions.Clear();
        ChatCenter.CurrentCenter.Unsubscribe<ChatMessage>(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the message by verifying the callbacks can be invoked, then invoking them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void ProcessMessage(ChatMessage message)
    {
        // If any of the conditions fail, don't process.
        if (conditions.Any(condition => !condition(message)))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Invoke each callback.
        foreach (var callback in this.callbacks)
        {
            callback(message);
        }
    }
}
```

#### IMessage and implementation

Lastly is the `IMessage` interface and a sample implementation for a chat message.

```
/// <summary>
/// A contract for objects wanting to dispatch message notifications.
/// </summary>
public interface IMessage
{
    void Dispatch(ISubscriptionHandler handler);
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides methods for dispatching notifications to subscription handlers
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessageType">The type of the message type.</typeparam>
public class MessageBase<TMessageType> : IMessage where TMessageType : class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatches this message instance to the given handler for processing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handler">The handler.</param>
    public void Dispatch(ISubscriptionHandler handler)
    {
        // We must convert ourself to our generic type.
        var msg = this as TMessageType;
        if (msg == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var target = handler as ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessageType>;
        if (target == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Dispatch ourself strongly typed to a protected version
        // of the Dispatch method.
        this.Dispatch(target, msg);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatches the given message to the given handler.
    /// Children classes can override this method to perform custom dispatching
    /// if needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The handler.</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispatch(ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessageType> target, TMessageType message)
    {
        // Let the handler process this message.
        target.ProcessMessage(message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A chat message.
/// </summary>
public class ChatMessage : MessageBase<ChatMessage>
{
    public ChatMessage(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

#### Unit Test Demonstrating usage.

```
[TestClass]
public class SubscriptionResultTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Conditions_for_publish_are_met_and_dispatched()
    {
        // Arrange
        var chatHandler = new ChatMessageHandler();
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 3;
        var center = ChatCenter.CurrentCenter;

        // Subscribe
        center.Subscribe<ChatMessage>()
            .If(msg => x == 1)
            .If(msg => y == 2)
            .If(msg => z == 3)
            .Dispatch(msg => x = 3)
            .Dispatch(msg =>
            {
                y = 10;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                z = 15;
            });

        // Act
        center.Publish(new ChatMessage(string.Empty));

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(3, x);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, y);
        Assert.AreEqual(15, z);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Object_can_unsubscribe()
    {
        // Arrange
        var chatHandler = new ChatMessageHandler();
        int y = 2;
        var callback = new Action<IMessage>(msg => y = 10);

        // Subscribe
        ISubscriptionHandler handler = ChatCenter.CurrentCenter.Subscribe<ChatMessage>()
            .Dispatch(callback);
        handler.Unsubscribe();

        // Act
        ChatCenter.CurrentCenter.Publish(new ChatMessage(string.Empty));

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, y);
    }
}
```

One of the downsides of how I've built it is that my callback's are not strongly typed to the subscribed IMessage implementation, so I can't access any custom properties within each IMessage implementation during a dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ISubscriptionHandler Subscribe<T>()
```

I think this is a confusing interface. I would expect something along the lines of:

```
ISubscription Subscribe<T>(ISubscriptionHandler<T> handler)
```

where `ISubscriptionHandler<T>` would contain any predicates and code that should be dispatched when a message arrives and `ISubscription` can be used to unsubscribe.

---

Why is `ChatCenter` a singleton? This is especially weird since you're using unit tests, which should be independent.

---

```
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
```

If you don't want to add documentation comments for everything, that's fine. But there is no reason to have empty comments like these cluttering up your code.

---

You already realized that you need to separate the non-generic `ISubscriptionHandler` and the generic `ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessage>`. But since you already have that, you should use the generic version as much as possible and use the non-generic version only when necessary (pretty much just around the `Dictionary`).

This would mean you could get rid of the `IMessage.Dispatch()` step and for example the core of `ChatCenter.Publish()` could look like this (explicitly typing the iteration variable of a `foreach` works as a cast):

```
foreach (ISubscriptionProcessor<T> handler in listeners[typeof(T)])
{
    handler.ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

---

```
public interface ISubscriptionHandler
{
    ISubscriptionHandler If(Func<IMessage, bool> condition);

    ISubscriptionHandler Dispatch(Action<IMessage> message);

    void Unsubscribe();
}
```

Even if you made this type generic as I suggested above, this interface still feels clunky to me. Why do you even need multiple conditions and multiple handler delegates? And if you think that having single condition is not enough, why would multiple conditions joined by AND be enough?

Just allow only a single condition and if the user wants something more complicated, they can create that complicated condition themselves.

---

```
Action<IMessage> message
```

This delegate is not a message, so it shouldn't be called that. Maybe something like `messageProcessor`?

---

```
public interface ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessageType>
```

Generic parameter can't be anything else than a type, so you need to spell it out, just `TMessage` is enough. (Also “The type of the message type.” is confusing.)

---

```
public class ChatMessageHandler : ISubscriptionProcessor<ChatMessage>
```

This whole type doesn't contain anything that's specific to `ChatMessage`. Instead, it should be a generic type like:

```
public class MessageHandler<TMessage> : ISubscriptionProcessor<TMessage>
```

---

```
var msg = this as TMessageType;
if (msg == null)
{
    return;
}
```

This situation would mean that the current type of message is broken (it has incorrect type parameter). I think the right behavior in that case is to complain loudly by throwing an exception, not silently doing nothing.

This way, the programmer who wrote the faulty message type will realize their mistake very soon, they won't have to spend time figuring out why their message doesn't seem to do anything.

Very similar argument applies to the following `handler` check.

Comment: The reasoning behind Subscribe<T>() instead of Subscribe<T>(ISubscriptionHandler<T> handler) was that the object just knows it wants to subscribe to Chat Messages, I didnt want to expose what handler was being used to it. This let users replace handlers with custom handlers and it would be reflected through-out the engine. I could still go the route you suggested, but use a factory to create the handlers, so I still have a level of indirection.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, I do like having the ISubscription returning, so they can unsubscribe from the returned object. I also didn't think about using the generic interface everywhere except the dictionary. I made the ChatCenter a singleton (could have been static too I suppose) in order to keep the cache of handlers alive. Is there different way of doing this that you would recommend?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger I don't understand why would you need to worry about keeping `ChatCenter` alive. As long as publishers that are alive have a reference to it, it will stay alive.

Comment: As an example, Player1 connects, instances a ChatCenter, Subscribes its callback. Player2 connects, instances a ChatCenter and subscribes. The subscriptions are not stored in a shared collection. So when Game instances ChatCenter and publishes, it won't publish to the previous two that registered. It will be a new instance. I could make the handler collection static to share it across instances of ChatCenter as an alternative.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger I don't understand what would another implementation of handler do differently. But you can still keep the signature I suggested even with different implementations not chosen by the user: the parameter of `Subscribe()` would be a simple type that just holds the data and the real handler would be created inside `Subscribe()` based on that data and any other logic you need.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger In your example, Player1, Player2 and Game need access to the same instance of `ChatCenter`. But it shouldn't be the job of `ChatCenter` to take care of that, it should be the job of your business logic. For example, if both players have access to Game, them use the Game object to share the `ChatCenter`.

Comment: Ok, good point, I will take a look at doing that.

Comment: I re-designed it, taking your recommendations in to consideration, and posted a new code review post on it. Would you mind taking a look at it and giving me feedback on it? I would appreciate it! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77855/communicating-messages-to-objects

Answer (score 2):

**Bug ?**

Only focusing on

> ```
> internal void Unsubscribe<T>(ISubscriptionHandler handler) where T : class, IMessage
> {
>     if (!listeners.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     listeners.Remove(typeof(T));
> }
> ```

- the input parameter `handler` is not used.
- assume you have more than one item which subscribed for a givven type. If one will unsubscribe the other won't receive any messages

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The dictionary was originally s single handler, so removing the type was all I needed. I changed it to a collection of handlers while posting and missed changing this method