# Communicating messages to objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, mediator

In my MUD game engine, I built a messaging api that allows objects to subscribe to concrete implementations of an `IMessage` interface. Is there anything glaringly bad about the approach I have taken?

The intended use-case is for objects, such as an IPlayer implementation, to subscribe to WhisperMessage and ShoutMessage publishes. When a player sends a chat message, a mediator performs a `Publish` for an instance of `ShoutMessage` and all IPlayer implementations that subscribed are given the message.

#### IMessage, it's generic counterpart, base class and implementation

```
public interface IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the content of the message</returns>
    object GetContent();
}    

/// <summary>
/// Allows for receiving the content of a message
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TContent">The type of the content.</typeparam>
public interface IMessage<TContent> : IMessage where TContent : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    TContent Content { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the message content</returns>
    new TContent GetContent();
}

public abstract class MessageBase<TContentType> : IMessage<TContentType> where TContentType : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    public TContentType Content { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content of the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns the message content
    /// </returns>
    public TContentType GetContent()
    {
        return this.Content;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Returns the content of the message
    /// </returns>
    object IMessage.GetContent()
    {
        return this.GetContent();
    }
}

public class ShoutMessage : MessageBase<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ShoutMessage"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public ShoutMessage(string message)
    {
        this.Content = message;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used when an object needs to send a private message to a character.
/// </summary>
public class WhisperMessage : MessageBase<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WhisperMessage"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
    public WhisperMessage(string message, ICharacter target)
    {
        this.Content = message;
        this.Target = target;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the target that this message is intended for.
    /// </summary>
    public ICharacter Target { get; private set; }
}
```

#### Notification handlers

```
public interface ISubscription
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the subscription is being unsubscribed.
    /// </summary>
    event Action<NotificationArgs> Unsubscribing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="ISubscription"/> is active.
    /// </summary>
    bool IsActive { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the registerd callbacks from receiving notifications.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="notificationCenter">The notification center.</param>
    void Unsubscribe();
}

public interface INotification<TMessageType> : ISubscription where TMessageType : class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the specified action for callback when a notification is fired for T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The message being posted along with the subscription registered to receive the post.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    void Register(
        Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback,
        Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the message, invoking the registered callbacks if their conditions are met.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    void ProcessMessage(TMessageType message);
}

internal class Notification<TMessage> : INotification<TMessage> where TMessage : class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The callbacks invoked when the handler processes the messages.
    /// </summary>
    private Action<TMessage, ISubscription> callback;

    /// <summary>
    /// The conditions that must be met in order to fire the callbacks.
    /// </summary>
    private Func<TMessage, bool> condition;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the subscription is being unsubscribed.
    /// </summary>
    public event Action<NotificationArgs> Unsubscribing;

    public bool IsActive { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a callback for when a chat message is published by the MessageCenter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processor">The message.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Register(
        Action<TMessage, ISubscription> processor,
        Func<TMessage, bool> condition)
    {
        this.callback = processor;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.IsActive = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the handler from notifications. This cleans up all of the callback references and conditions.
    /// </summary>
    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        this.callback = null;
        this.condition = null;

        try
        {
            this.OnUnsubscribing();
        }
        // TODO: Write custom SubscriptionException to catch.
        finally
        {
            this.IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes the message by verifying the callbacks can be invoked, then invoking them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void ProcessMessage(TMessage message)
    {
        if (this.condition == null)
        {
            this.callback(message, this);
            return;
        }

        if (!this.condition(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.callback(message, this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnUnsubscribing()
    {
        var handler = this.Unsubscribing;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        handler(new NotificationArgs(this, typeof(TMessage)));
    }
}

public class NotificationArgs
{
    public NotificationArgs(ISubscription subscription, Type messageType)
    {
        this.Subscription = subscription;
        this.MessageType = messageType;
    }

    public ISubscription Subscription { get; private set; }

    public Type MessageType { get; private set; }
}
```

#### NotificationManager

```
public interface INotificationCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up a new handler and returns it for subscription set up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMessageType">An IMessage implementation that the given handler will be provided when messages are dispatched</typeparam>
    /// <param name="handler">The handler used to process incoming messages.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns an ISubscription that can be used to unsubscribe.</returns>
    ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback, Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null) where TMessageType : class, IMessage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the specified message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    void Publish<TMessageType>(TMessageType message) where TMessageType : class, IMessage;
}

/// <summary>
/// The mediator for all messaging
/// </summary>
public class NotificationManager : INotificationCenter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of subscribed listeners
    /// </summary>
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>> listeners =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<ISubscription>>();

    private object listenerCollectionLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribe publications for the message type specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TMessageType"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISubscription Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType, ISubscription> callback, Func<TMessageType, bool> condition = null) where TMessageType : class, IMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(TMessageType);

        // Create our key if it doesn't exist along with an empty collection as the value.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(messageType))
        {
            listeners.TryAdd(messageType, new List<ISubscription>());
        }

        // Add our notification to our listener collection so we can publish to it later, then return it.
        // TODO: Move instancing the Notification in to a Factory.
        var handler = new Notification<TMessageType>();
        handler.Register(callback, condition);
        handler.Unsubscribing += this.Unsubscribe;

        List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[messageType];
        lock (listenerCollectionLock)
        {
            subscribers.Add(handler);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Publishes the specified message to all subscribers
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class, IMessage
    {
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (INotification<T> handler in listeners[typeof(T)])
        {
            handler.ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribes the specified handler by removing their handler from our collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The message Type you want to unsubscribe from</typeparam>
    /// <param name="subscription">The subscription to unsubscribe.</param>
    private void Unsubscribe(NotificationArgs args)
    {
        // If the key doesn't exist or has an empty collection we just return.
        // We will leave the key in there for future subscriptions to use.
        if (!listeners.ContainsKey(args.MessageType) || listeners[args.MessageType].Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Remove the subscription from the collection associated with the key.
        List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[args.MessageType];
        lock (listenerCollectionLock)
        {
            subscribers.Remove(args.Subscription);
        }

        args.Subscription.Unsubscribing -= this.Unsubscribe;
    }
}
```

#### Unit Tests

The following unit tests show how I (and 3rd party devs using the engine) will use the API.

```
public class NotificationManagerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Runtime.Game - NotificationManager")]
    public void Publish_invokes_callbacks()
    {
        bool callbackCalled = false;
        string messageContent = "Test";
        var notificationCenter = new NotificationManager();
        notificationCenter.Subscribe<ShoutMessage>((msg, sub) =>
            {
                if (msg.Content == messageContent)
                {
                    callbackCalled = true;
                }
            });

        // Act
        notificationCenter.Publish(new ShoutMessage(messageContent));

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(callbackCalled);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Runtime.Game - NotificationManager")]
    public void Handler_can_unsubscribe()
    {
        var notificationCenter = new NotificationManager();
        int callCount = 0;

        // Build our notification.
        ISubscription subscriber = notificationCenter.Subscribe<MessageFixture>(
            (message, sub) => callCount++);

        // Subscribe our notification and publish a new message
        notificationCenter.Publish(new MessageFixture("Test"));

        // Act
        // Unsubscribe the notification and attempt a new publish
        subscriber.Unsubscribe();
        notificationCenter.Publish(new MessageFixture("Test"));

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, callCount, "The callbacks were not fired properly");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Runtime.Game - NotificationManager")]
    public void Handler_receives_only_its_message()
    {
        // Set up the first handler
        var notificationCenter = new NotificationManager();
        notificationCenter.Subscribe<MessageFixture>(
            (message, sub) => 
                ExceptionFactory.ThrowIf<InvalidOperationException>(message.GetType() != typeof(MessageFixture)));
        notificationCenter.Subscribe<SecondaryMessageFixture>(
            (message, sub) => 
                ExceptionFactory.ThrowIf<InvalidOperationException>(message.GetType() != typeof(SecondaryMessageFixture)));

        // Act
        notificationCenter.Publish(new MessageFixture("Test"));
        notificationCenter.Publish(new SecondaryMessageFixture(new GameComponentFixture()));
    }
}
```

I plan on using the `NotificationManager` not just for chat messages, but game event messages that will get logged to the server console. I plan on building commanding around this, so a user enters a command that gets published, and a subscribing `CommandManager` will receive the message and run it through a TPL data flow to process the command in to an `IPlayerCommand` that maps to the supplied command and executed.

Do you guys feel my `NotificationManager` will be responsible for to much and I should break it in to different managers per message catagory (events, chat, commanding) or is it acceptable to run them all through the `NotificationManager`?

My though being that I would build different INotification implementations so that the messages published can be processed differently. Instead of a shared `Notification` class, I'd have `ChatNotification` and `CommandNotification`, with each handling how the notification message is processed differently (example being `CommandNotification` firing a `TPL Dataflow`).

I felt that having the `NotificationManager` just hand-off the publications to each `INotification` instance and not really holding any logic, would keep with SRP and allow several notification categories to be used with the same object.

I'd appreciate your input

Answer (score 3):

```
object GetContent();
TContent Content { get; }
new TContent GetContent();
```

How is `GetContent()` (both versions) useful? The non-generic `IMessage` could be just a marker interface, with no methods.

I'm not even sure about the usefulness of `Content`, since it seems it doesn't contain all the content of the message. E.g. treating `WhisperMessage` as a `IMessage<string>` won't give you everything.

---

```
if (this.condition == null)
{
    this.callback(message, this);
    return;
}

if (!this.condition(message))
{
    return;
}

this.callback(message, this);
```

This is unnecessarily complicated, you could simplify it to:

```
if (this.condition == null || this.condition(message))
{
    this.callback(message, this);
}
```

---

```
List<ISubscription> subscribers = listeners[messageType];
lock (listenerCollectionLock)
{
    subscribers.Add(handler);
}
```

You could lock here (and in `Unsubscribe()`) on `subscribers`. That way, adding subscribers for two different message types could happen at the same time.

Comment: Nice catch on locking on the local `subscribers`.

Answer (score 2):

**`IMessage<TContent>`**

Here you have a property `TContentType Content` and also a `TContentType GetContent()` method, which are just returning the same. If you assume that returning the `content` will be fast (there won't be time consuming calculation involved) you should make it a property otherwise a method. Having both is a code smell (at least for me).

**`Notification<TMessage>`**

The `ProcessMessage()` message could be rewritten to combine the check for `condition == null` and `!this.condition(message)` to remove the small code duplication.

```
public void ProcessMessage(TMessage message)
{

    if (this.condition != null && !this.condition(message))
    {
        return;
    }

    this.callback(message, this);
}
```

**`NotificationManager`**

In the `Subscribe<TMessageType>()` method you should remove the assignment of the dictionary value to a `subscribers` variable because you don't use it afterwards.

```
lock (listenerCollectionLock)
{
    listeners[messageType].Add(handler);
}
```

The same is true for the `Unsubscribe()` method

```
lock (listenerCollectionLock)
{
    listeners[args.MessageType].Remove(args.Subscription);
}
```

**General**

- If the primary purpose is to send `String` messages I wouldn't go the generic route.
- Using XML documentation is good, but it should be complete.
  For the `INotificationCenter.SubScribe()` method you are missing the documentation for the condition.
- I appreciate the using of braces `{}` for single if statements
- I appreciate the using of guard clauses/conditions to save horizontal space

Comment: The `subscribers` collection has been removed. It was left over from when the collection was a ConcurrentBag and I had to do `TryGet(out subscribers)`. I will go back over my comments and make sure their fully documented.

Comment: I like your point on the `TContentType GetContent()`. It doesn't do anything other than just return the `TContentType` property. I'll remove the method from the generic interface and just use the property.